# Nuxt Apollo with dynamic headers for a session based authentication

Tags: session, cookies, nuxt.js, apollo

Apollo is not storing the header from the query dynamically.

[pages/index.vue](https://github.com/SuddenlyRust/session-based-auth/blob/master/pages/index.vue)

```js
methods: {
  fetchCars() {
    const token = Cookies.get('XSRF-TOKEN')

    console.log(token) //  Token is shown in console

    this.$apollo.query({
      query: gql`
        query {
          cars {
            uuid
            name
          }
        }
      `,
      headers: {
        'X-XSRF-TOKEN': token, // ⭕ Fetch without header
      },
    })
  },
},
```

Is there a way to set the header value new for every Apollo request?

I have a separate Frontend and Backend. For the Frontend I am using Nuxt.js with Apollo. I want to have a session based communication with my server. For this reason I need to send the CSRF-Token with every Request.

Now the problem: On the first load of the page there is no Cookie set on the browser. I do a GET-Request on every initialization of my Nuxt application.

[plugins/csrf.js](https://github.com/SuddenlyRust/session-based-auth/blob/master/plugins/csrf.js)

```js
fetch('http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/csrf-cookie', {
  credentials: 'include',
})
```

Now I have a valid Cookie set on my side and want to communicate with the GraphQL Server but my header is not set dynamically in the query. Does anyone know how I can solve this?

My Laravel Backend is throwing now a 419 Token Mismatch Exception because I did not send a CSRF-Token with my request.

Link to the repository: https://github.com/SuddenlyRust/session-based-auth

**[SOLVED]** Working solution: https://github.com/SuddenlyRust/session-based-auth/commit/de8fb9c18b00e58655f154f8d0c95a677d9b685b Thanks to the help of `kofh` in the Nuxt Apollo discord channel

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In order to accomplish this, we need to access the code that gets run every time a `fetch` happens. This code lives inside your Apollo client's HttpLink. While the `@nuxtjs/apollo` module gives us many options, we can't quite configure this at such a high level.

### Step 1: Creating a client plugin

As noted in the [setup section](https://github.com/nuxt-community/apollo-module#setup) of the Apollo module's docs, we can supply a path to a plugin that will define a `clientConfig`:

```js
// nuxt.config.js
{
  apollo: {
    clientConfigs: {
      default: '~/plugins/apollo-client.js'
    }
  }
}
```

This plugin should export a function which receives the [nuxt context](https://nuxtjs.org/api/context#__layout). It should return the configuration to be passed to the [`vue-cli-plugin-apollo`'s `createApolloClient` utility](https://github.com/Akryum/vue-cli-plugin-apollo/blob/master/graphql-client/src/index.js#L14). You don't need to worry about that file, but it is how `@nuxtjs/apollo` creates the client internally.

### Step 2: Creating the custom `httpLink`

In `createApolloClient`'s options, we see we can disable `defaultHttpLink` and instead supply our own `link`. `link` needs to be the output of Apollo's official `createHttpLink` utility, docs for which can be found [here](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/link/links/http/). The option we're most interested in is the `fetch` option which as the docs state, is

> a `fetch` compatible API for making a request

This boils down to meaning a function that takes `uri` and `options` parameters and returns a `Promise` that represents the network interaction.

### Step 3: Creating the custom `fetch` method

As stated above, we need a function that takes `uri` and `options` and returns a promise. This function will be a simple passthrough to the standard `fetch` method (you may need to add `isomorphic-fetch` to your dependencies and import it here depending on your setup).

We'll extract your cookie the same as you did in your question, and then set it as a header. The fetch function should look like this:

```js
(uri, options) => {
  const token = Cookies.get('XSRF-TOKEN')

  options.headers['X-XSRF-TOKEN'] = token

  return fetch(uri, options)
}
```

### Putting it all together

Ultimately, your `~/plugins/apollo-client.js` file should look something like this:

```js
import { createHttpLink } from 'apollo-link-http'
import fetch from 'isomorphic-fetch'

export default function(context) {
  return {
    defaultHttpLink: false,
    link: createHttpLink({
      uri: '/graphql',
      credentials: 'include',
      fetch: (uri, options) => {
        const token = Cookies.get('XSRF-TOKEN')

        options.headers['X-XSRF-TOKEN'] = token

        return fetch(uri, options)
      }
    })
  }
}
```